# Should I award a bounty even if I'm not completely satisfied?

Tags: discussion, bounty

I offered a bounty to an old question in order to bring more attention to it. After the week the bounty was valid, only one new answer is there and it's not exactly what I was looking for. It answers some of the questions but not all of them and overall it's not very helpful for me. On the other hand it answers the original question partially and I appreciate that the person put some effort in answering an old question which it's more than anyone else did.

Is there any generally accepted way how to decide whether to award the bounty to this answer or let it expire?

Comment: It's up to you.  You're free to award it however you want, including not at all (a post may be auto-awarded half of the bounty though; see the FAQ on bounties for the criteria).

Comment: @Servy I know about the auto-awarding. This is not the case though as the only answer didn't get any upvotes so far. But thanks for mentioning it. As for (not) awarding it I realize that it's my choice but I wanted to know if there is some general consensus on that or any arguments I should consider that didn't occurred to me before.

Answer (score 3):

It's entirely up to you, the bounty poster. Awarding the bounty means that there's no (additional) incentive for other users anymore to answer your question. So if you're on the fence, you'll want to wait until the last possible moment with this anyway. From there the option is to let the bounty go to waste entirely or to award it. Unless the answer is *completely* useless, it seems like a waste to, well, waste the bounty.

But again, that's entirely up to you in the end...

Comment: ... And anyway, waiting until the end also maximizes the reward for answerers and for you, as more people will see it and maybe vote.

Answer (score 1):

Simple reasoning time. But I'd like to say up front that there is actually little reason to debate how to handle bounties; I believe there is no strict ruling around them with the full intention of making it entirely up to you when to post one and to dictate when it is "good enough" to award them.

The following is simply my interpretation.

Q: What was the intent behind posting the bounty?
A: to give an incentive for people to invest time in providing a -good- answer.

Q: does a half-answer apply?
A: NO

Q: so should the bounty be awarded if the answer is not complete?
A: NO

I'd rather let the bounty 'go to waste' (its only internet points) than invalidating the reason why you posted it to begin with. This is not about compromise or being nice; its about good enough or not good enough.